Dock Position change on screen rotation
I'm trying to move the position of my Dock on my Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga X13 running Ubuntu 24.04 as follows:

Landscape - I would like the dock to be on the left hand side
Portrait - I would like the dock to be on the bottom

I have seen a Python script from here on AskUbuntu to do the same thing, but for me it does not work, as it is 5 years old I am wondering of some of the code to detect the screen rotation works different for Wayland?
Original answer for 18.04 is here: Ubuntu 18.04: Changing dock location on monitor rotation
I have tried the following commands from the Python code
run_command("gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-position BOTTOM")

and
run_command("gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-position LEFT")

and these work fine, so the thing I don't understand how to do is detect the screen rotation and why the code from the Python file linked doesn't work?
All quite new to Linux and Ubuntu so any help much appreciated.
